# Any difference between ios file:///var/mobile/Containers and file:///private/var/mobile/Containers?

Tags: ios, swift

Are they different or simple aliases?

I obtain the /private/var by running:

```
FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: folder, includingPropertiesForKeys: [], options: [])
```

And the second is created with a simple:

```
data.write(to: f, options: [.atomic])
```

where f is in the same directory as "folder"

Comment: print and share what this `folder` url object of yours looks like

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That are the same directories, as one can verify by retrieving the
“canonical path” for both:

```
let url1 = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/var/mobile/Containers/")
if let cp = (try? url1.resourceValues(forKeys: [.canonicalPathKey]))?.canonicalPath {
    print(cp)
    // "/private/var/mobile/Containers"

}
let url2 = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/private/var/mobile/Containers/")
if let cp = (try? url2.resourceValues(forKeys: [.canonicalPathKey]))?.canonicalPath {
    print(cp)
    // "/private/var/mobile/Containers"
}
```

In fact, `/var` is a symbolic link to `/private/var`:

```
var buffer = Array<Int8>(repeating: 0, count: 1024)
if readlink("/var", &buffer, buffer.count) > 0 {
    print(String(cString: &buffer))
    // "private/var"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Swift users, using `URL.standardizedFileURL` eliminates the ambiguity/confusion caused by paths which contain soft links or other different elements that ultimately resolve to the same file.

Comment: This seems a bit simpler than the accepted answer. Is there any case in which using URL.standardizedFileURL would differ from using the .canonicalPathKey approach?

Comment: I can't find documentation to indicate that canonicalPathKey would or would not resolve to the identical path representation as standardizedFileURL.  But I'm not sure why it matters.  The real question is, is there a case in which using standardizedFileURL will not work?  I doubt the answer is yes.  Just use standardizedFileURL.  :)