# Different path after appendingPathComponent(_:)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to access json files I copied to the `~/Documents` folder.

When I check what files are available there, it has those files in an array with paths beginning with `file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/95982B17-2C5F-4E3F-8AD7-FB90F557B991/Documents/`:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
       if let docDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
           do {
               let docs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: docDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: [], options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
               print("Files in ~/Documents are: ")
               for doc in docs {
                   print(doc)
               }

           } catch let error {
               Logger.printLogEntry(message: "Could not get content of documents directory: \(error.localizedDescription)", category: .dev
               )
           }
       }
```

But when I then add a path like so

```
let filePath = docDirectory.appendingPathComponent("products.json")
print("File Path is: ", filePath)
```

it gives me the following path: `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/95982B17-2C5F-4E3F-8AD7-FB90F557B991/Documents/`

This is different on the simulator; paths there remain the same (without the `private` stuff in front...

Can anyone explain that to me? To be clear, I need to copy / access in different methods, so understanding the way it's accessing differently is crucial to me.

Comment: Both paths are valid. On a real device, `/var` and `/private/var` are the same - one is a link to the other.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391830/any-difference-between-ios-file-var-mobile-containers-and-file-private-var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that hopefully for someone else to be more successful to get an answer when researching this:
`/var` and /private/var` point to the same folder on a real device, as one is an alias of the other, as mentioned in the comments above. So thanks to the commenters for their hints.

Comment: Even on a Mac, `/var` is a symlink pointing to `/private/var`. You can check this at the Terminal: `ls -l /var`